# ionic 3 angular http.post connection refused from firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, amazon-ec2, ionic3

i am having a ionic 3 angular app deployed on firebase static hosting. the piece in question looks like:

```
var data = {"message" : time,
                                "user_id" : user};
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/push', JSON.stringify(data))
          .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res);
          }, (err) => {
                    alert('error:' + err);
            console.log('error is:' +  err);
            reject(err);
          });
      });
```

the apiUrl is an amazon ec2 hosted REST service. This fails with error: 
Response with status 0 for url: null  and more details console logs shows:

```
POST https://ec2-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/push net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The request headers looks like:

```
Request URL:https://ec2-XX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/push
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
content-type:text/plain
Origin:https://myapp.firebaseapp.com
Referer:https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1
```

I have another deployment on a oracle compute base server. there this works just fine. The request looks like below on that server:

```
Request URL:http://ec2-XX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/push
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:34.228.152.99:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
 (12)
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:39
content-type:text/plain
Host:ec2-XX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Origin:http://my-server-ip
Referer:http://my-server-ip/osc/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1
```

Comment: Sounds like login credentials are wrong. If you're sure they are right, try clearing browser cache/cookies... Also what version of Firebase are you using. That possibly may make a difference..  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ - read footnote here... And have you set your project up yet? https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1

Comment: There is no security involved at all

Answer (score 0):

Most Likely its a CORS issue, you may have warnings in your browser inspector when you run the function.

You need a file in the top level called `poxy.conf.json` and populate it with something like this

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://xxxx.com",
    "secure": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

and then in your function do

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('name', encodeURI(name));
params = params.append('email', encodeURI(email));

this._http.get('/api/mypageorfolder', { params: params }).subscribe(
 data => {
 //console.log("data",data);
});
```

So you do a query string to `https://xxxx.com/mypageorfolder/?name=&email=`

And referencing

```
import { HttpParams, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {RequestOptions, Request, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

Remember to restart you app